# Generate a complete URL within a Yesod application

Tags: web-services, url, web, nginx, yesod

I mean that for example

```
YC.getUrlRender >>= enact where
    enact renderURL = renderURL HomeR
```

will result in "/", for example, and usually that's what you need.  However, I'm trying to crack email verification where the email has to contain the https://yesod.domain.com bit as well so that the user can click on the link to verify the new account.  Is it in fact possible to obtain that bit ?   In my deployment for example, the Yesod application is behind nginx, with the configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

so would the Yesod app even know that it was reached via https://myvps.hosting.com ?

Maybe the answer is to pass the information in via nginx, thus:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000?youEnteredVia=https://myvps.hosting.com;
}
```

although I'd want to use $1 or something to avoid that hard-coded URL, and I don't know how to pick up the value within the Yesod application but I'm sure MS's book has the information somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is the entire purpose around having the [`approot`](http://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.5/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/Yesod-Core.html#v:approot) class method, since it's not always possible to determine the correct application root based on the request itself. You may also want to look at [ApprootMiddleware](http://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.5/wai-extra-3.0.7.1/Network-Wai-Middleware-Approot.html).